# A happy instrumental song which plays during a flashback in Naruto Shippuden

Tags: naruto, music

In *Naruto Shippuden* episode 6 "Mission Cleared", there is a song at about 8:20 where Iruka treats Naruto to a bowl of ramen. The music plays when there is a flashback to Naruto asking Iruka to try on his headband. The song sounds instrumental and happy.

The same song is at the beginning to episode 2 before the title scene/Japanese rock music plays. The song I am looking for plays during a happy flashback. I have spent an hour looking for this song but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your are asking this one:

Naruto Shippuden OST 3 - Peaceful Theme

Link Below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1O04qZv3-4